# Does for WeightLoss Raw Garlic and Honey help? If Yes, How?

Tags: weight-loss, bodyweight

For Past 1 month I am reading one common Natural diagnosis for WeightLoss i.e. Honey dipped Raw Sliced Garlic. Following reason they give:-

[ARTICLE 1](https://food.ndtv.com/weight-loss/raw-garlic-and-honey-for-weight-loss-eat-this-combination-on-empty-stomach-to-lose-weight-fast-1909034)

> Perhaps Garlic's biggest health benefit is in aiding weight loss by
>   stimulating appetite and boosting digestion. As health experts often
>   say, a good digestive system is key to a quicker weight loss, honey
>   and garlic are the ideal companions for your weight loss journey.
>
> Raw garlic has a better nutritive profile than cooked garlic, making
>   the former a better weight loss agent. Similarly, consuming raw honey
>   early in the morning may help metabolise fat better.

[ARTICLE 2](http://www.menmomhealth.com/how-to-use-lemon-garlic-honey-for-weight-loss/)

> Garlic effectively increases the metabolism rate of your body.
>   Metabolism rate is the rate of calorie consumption by time. People who
>   easily store fat have low metabolism rate. The most effective
>   component of garlic is allicin, it increases the blood sugar
>   consumption rate in the body.

Is there any FACT in this? Can anyone confirm?

Comment: If there was a magical food that you eat and you lost weight, well, there wouldn't be so many obese people. The best way to lose weight is with a sustainable small caloric deficit and food that is both decent and enjoyable. If you got too fat, you eat the wrong stuff. To not gain all the weight again after stopping your diet, you need a long term plan. Imo your links sound like complete nonsense. If they don't provide numbers how much they increase your metabolic rate by, they are also useless for healthy weightloss even if they were true

Comment: First. I would encourage you to be aware of the Be Nice policy. Second, it was decided long ago that nutrition is off topic unless it is in the context of a fitness program, not a stand alone question. The weightloss tag exists for fitness programs designed for that goal. If you disagree, you are certainly welcome to raise the question on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main stimulant for weight loss is necessarily consuming less calories than you burn.

If you supplement a balanced, low-calorie diet with garlic-honey it may or may not accelerate the process. Remember that appetite boost is not always what you want when you want to lose weight.